# not able to deploy war file in jelastic cloud

Tags: glassfish, cloud, java-ee-6, jelastic

I developed a web application using java and mongodb. I used glassfish server.
I tried to deploy it on jelastic cloud service
I uploaded my war file. But when I run it after deploying the war file it shows a 404 error. Why? The project works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least few potential causes:

- your app needs some resources which are not started by default (such as DerbyDB). In this case you can check GlassFish log file - server_instance.log for more details.
- you are trying to get resources from wrong context, make sure you are trying to get it via correct context name

Comment: this did work..thanks..but how do i upload my database on the cloud as well

Comment: as I know each database has its own GUI based admin page, so you can upload dump over that admin page